# How to gracefully stop a HTTP2 server built with nghttp2 asio

Tags: boost-asio, http2, nghttp2

I am aware of how to use `nghttp2` asio library to build HTTP2 server and client applications.

The [documentation](https://nghttp2.org/documentation/asio_http2_server.h.html) says that there are `stop` and `join` APIs for gracefully stopping an HTTP2 server.

Is there any working example of using `stop` and `join`? In particular, as soon as `listen_and_serve` is called, the thread goes to a busy loop. Is it recommended to call `stop` from a different thread? Unfortunately no clue or example code is given in the documentation.

### EDIT:

Here is a working program where I am trying to stop the server on `SIGINT`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <nghttp2/asio_http2_server.h>

using namespace nghttp2::asio_http2;
using namespace nghttp2::asio_http2::server;

nghttp2::asio_http2::server::http2 myserver;
void signalHandler( int signum ) {
  std::cout << "Interrupt signal (" << signum << ") received." << std::endl;
  myserver.stop();
  myserver.join();
  exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  signal(SIGINT, signalHandler);
  std::thread::id this_id = std::this_thread::get_id();
  std::cout << "Main thread running at " << this_id << std::endl;
  boost::system::error_code ec;

  myserver.handle("/api/ping", [](const request &req, const response &res) {
    std::thread::id this_id = std::this_thread::get_id();
    std::cout << "Ping Request received at " << this_id << std::endl;
    req.on_data([](const uint8_t *data, std::size_t len){
      std::cerr.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(data), len);
      std::cerr << std::endl;
    });
    res.write_head(200);
    res.end("hello, ping\n");
  });

  if (myserver.listen_and_serve(ec, "0.0.0.0", "8080")) {
    std::cerr << "error: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

The execution hangs at `myserver.stop()` after pressing `Control+C`. I tried using only `myserver.stop()` or `myserver.join()` but without any improvement. If I directly call `exit(0)` like below, the server stops with a segmentation fault.

```
void signalHandler( int signum ) {
  std::cout << "Interrupt signal (" << signum << ") received." << std::endl;
  myserver.stop();
  myserver.join();
  exit(0);
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `asynchronous` parameter in `listen_and_serve` should be set to `true`, default is `asynchronous = false`.

Note that the server will not exit and wait on the `myserver.join()` until the last client connection is closed. When you call `myserver.close()`, the server stops accepting new connections.

A working solution below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <nghttp2/asio_http2_server.h>

using namespace nghttp2::asio_http2;
using namespace nghttp2::asio_http2::server;

nghttp2::asio_http2::server::http2 myserver;
void signalHandler( int signum ) {
  std::cout << "Interrupt signal (" << signum << ") received." << std::endl;
  myserver.stop();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  signal(SIGINT, signalHandler);
  std::thread::id this_id = std::this_thread::get_id();
  boost::system::error_code ec;

  myserver.handle("/api/ping", [](const request &req, const response &res) {
    std::thread::id this_id = std::this_thread::get_id();
    std::cout << "Ping Request received at " << this_id << std::endl;
    req.on_data([](const uint8_t *data, std::size_t len){
      std::cerr.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(data), len);
      std::cerr << std::endl;
    });
    res.write_head(200);
    res.end("hello, ping\n");
  });

  if (myserver.listen_and_serve(ec, "0.0.0.0", "8080", true)) {
    std::cerr << "error: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
  }
  myserver.join();
}
```